# Populate an Excel table with a collection object

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to create a macro that let the user input, let say, values in 20 different cells that will then (upon clicking a button) add this information to a database on another sheet to be used later.

I have successfully written the code to store these 20 different values in a collection object and now I'm trying to write the later part of the code in which I want this collection object to populate let say row 8 in the table.

The outline looks as follows:

1. Add 20 different values to a collection object
2. Go to a different sheet (the data table)
3. See if the last row of the table is empty, if it is not, then add a row else go to step 4
4. Populate the appropriate row in the table with the values in the collection object.

I could just create a loop with a counter etc., but perhaps a more sophisticated solution exist?

```
Sub AddDataRow(myCol As Collection)    
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Set sheet = Worksheets("Databas")
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects("Table1")

    If table.ListColumns("Projektnamn").Range.End(xlDown) <> "" Then
        table.ListRows.Add
    Else

    End If
```

Comment: Assuming `DataBodyRange` exists, might be more reliable to use `table.ListColumns("Projektnamn").DataBodyRange(table.ListColumns("Projektnamn").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count)` instead of `Range.End(xlDown)`. I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but I don't think there is any native/convenience method for transferring a collection's contents to an Excel table/`ListObject` -- which I think is what you've asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think counter and looping is the best bet for a Collection object. If you want to set a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime, you could use a Dictionary object instead of a Collection object. With a Dictionary you could use the Items or Keys method to write to a range in one shot rather than looping.

```
Sub test()

    Dim dc As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set dc = New Scripting.Dictionary

    dc.Add "1", "1"
    dc.Add "2", "2"
    dc.Add "3", "3"

    Sheet1.ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add.Range.Value = dc.Items

End Sub
```

[image: listobject row added]

I used to be resistant to using Dictionaries because I didn't want that external reference. But once I got over that (and have had no problems), I prefer Dictionaries in almost all cases.